# Why does Phoenix Colossus refer to Kitty as 'Katya'?

Tags: comics, wolverine-and-the-x-men, marvel

In Wolverine and the X-Men, Kitty and Piotr have a date. But he refers to Kitty as Katya. Is this just a russian form of Kathleen/Kathy/Kitty? Or is he saying something else?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, Katya '*Катя*' is the [usual short form for Yekaterina](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katya) '*[Екатерина](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%95%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0)*', the Russian form of Catherine/Katherine.